# How do I get all tags for a query?

Tags: mysql

I am using the 'Toxi' solution as described in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810356/how-to-implement-tag-system) for a tagging system. I would like to search for any question with the tag 'Apple'. I also need to return all the other tags for that question, but my query is only returning the 'Apple' tag:

```
SELECT b.id, allTags.* , GROUP_CONCAT( t.name order by t.name SEPARATOR ',') AS allTags
FROM tagmap bt, bookmark b, tag t
WHERE bt.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t.name = 'Apple')
AND b.id = bt.bookmark_id
GROUP BY b.id
```

gives me:

```
...,'...','...','...','2013-10-07','Apple' # only the matching tag...I need all the others
```

How do I get the following?:

```
...,'...','...','...','2013-10-07','Apple,Tim Cook,iPhone,iPad' # the rest of the tags for this question
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
SELECT b.id,
       alltags.*,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.name ORDER BY t1.name SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM   tag t1) AS allTags
FROM   tagmap bt,
       bookmark b,
       tag t
WHERE  bt.tag_id = t.tag_id
       AND ( t.name = 'Apple' )
       AND b.id = bt.bookmark_id
GROUP  BY b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this condtion

```
AND (  t.name  NOT LIKE '%Apple%' )
```