# Logical AND in SQL statement

Tags: java, database, hibernate, h2

I have a table which contains two columns, the first one contains a name and the second one contains a tag, so the name can have multiple tags, and the tags contains multiple names.

What I want to do is to write an SQL query that returns all the names that contains *ALL* the tags, which means that I must do AND operations in the SQL itself,  my method takes a list that contains the tags, and it returns all the names that belongs to *ALL* tags, for example, If I passed 3 tags; A,B and C and there is a name has the tags: A and B, it will not be returned because it doesn't contains C.

Comment: could you pls share the queries?

Comment: Which database are you using??  SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres?

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  I'll remove my answer as it is most likely not relevant.  "TOP 1" is a MSSQL convention.

Comment: @Bohemian My question is duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810356/how-to-implement-tag-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this will work:

```
SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE Tag IN ('list', 'of', 'tags') 
GROUP BY Name HAVING count(Name) = <counter of number of tags to Search>;
```