# Implementing tag system with multiple tables

Tags: database, postgresql, polymorphism, tagging

I am trying to implement tag system similar to one which StackOverflow has. Obviously I've read multiple articles including this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810510/1039952).

However my scenario is little bit different

- there will be limited amount of tags which can be only created by user with higher privilege (anybody can assign a tag there). This excludes option #1 (from SO question I linked above, each tag is inserted directly into the tables `tags` column and then it's queried with `LIKE`) I guess
- there are also multiple tables in DB which can be tagged (currently five)

Especially second criteria makes it harder so these are my thoughts

- I could follow option #3, have table `tags` and have M:N relationship with each table. However that would make searching harder (imagine that join if the table number grows) and also I need to tell which table (application module) matches the tag in a search result
- I could use some kind of polymorphism but I am pretty new to this concept regarding to the databases so is this something which fits to this problem well?

I use newest version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Post the options.

Comment: It's in the question I have linked

Comment: If this question is the same as the other it should be closed. Otherwise all elements of the question should be in the question.

Comment: It's not the same, this question extends original one to different problem (IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PostgreSQL, you have the option of some field types which aren't available for other databases.  Particularly, arrays and JSON fields.  I did some performance comparisons of the various methods in [a blog post](http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html).  Arrays and JSONB were definitely better options than a tags table for any search which needed to combine multiple tags.

Given that, I would recommend creating a tags column for each table on which you want to have tags, either an array or a JSONB column, depending.  If you need to search over multiple tables, I'd suggest a UNION query instead of having a single monolithic tags table which joins to everything.

Comment: I thought about that but wouldn't UNION impact performance a lot while doing it over couple of tables?

Comment: Only if you're going to join the result against something else.  Since you're collating 5 tables, you'll have to UNION *something*.