# How can I quickly search posts/listings using multiple tags?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

My directory site currently uses the ["toxi" table structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810510/10095602) for tagging listings.

My posts table has around 5 million records and the map table has around 15 million records.

I use terms to store all kinds of information like author, publisher, subject, medium (e.g. audio, video, etc.). And a post can have multiple multiple terms for each taxonomy (multiple authors, multiple subjects, etc).

Searching for posts based on a single term_id takes about four second to return results which is pretty lousy, but it takes 40 seconds to return results using multiple terms.

I need a more efficient solution, but I can't figure out if it's my queries that are inefficient or my table structure.

== SINGLE TERM SEARCH QUERY ==

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_taxonomy_term_map ON (posts.ID = post_taxonomy_term_map.object_id)
WHERE post_taxonomy_term_map.term_id=$term1
```

== MULTIPLE TERMS SEARCH QUERY ==

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post_taxonomy_term_map m, posts p
WHERE m.term_id IN ($term1, $term2, $term3)
AND p.ID = m.object_id
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING COUNT( p.ID )=3
```

## TABLES & COLUMNS

**posts** { ID, post_title, etc... }

PRIMARY     ID

**taxonomy_terms** { term_id, term_label, term_slug, etc. }

PRIMARY     term_id

**post_taxonomy_term_map** { map_id, object_id, taxonomy, term_id}

PRIMARY     map_id

INDEX       object_id

INDEX       term_id

INDEX       taxonomy

NOTE: post_taxonomy_term_map.object_id relates to the posts.ID value

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

For your first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_taxonomy_term_map
    ON posts.ID = post_taxonomy_term_map.object_id
WHERE post_taxonomy_term_map.term_id = $term1
```

a composite index on `(term_id, object_id)`.  This index includes `term_id`, which one or your indices was already doing, but it also covers the join by including `object_id`.  Assuming the `WHERE` clause is deemed restrictive enough by the optimizer to use the index, this should perform better than what you currently have.

```
CREATE INDEX some_idx ON post_taxonomy_term_map(term_id, object_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the main performance problem is due to the many:many table that TOXI asks for.  It can be eliminated:

```
CREATE TABLE Tags (
    tag VARHAR(...) NOT NULL,
    bid INT ... NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(tag, bid),
    INDEX(bid, tag)
)
```

Notes:

- This is better than TOXI in that it does not go through an extra many:many table, which makes optimization difficult.
- Sure, my approach may be slightly more bulky (than TOXI) due to the redundant tags, but that is a small percentage of the *whole* database, and the performance improvements may be significant.
- It is highly scalable.
- It does not have (because it does not need) a surrogate `AUTO_INCREMENT` PK.  Hence, it is better than Scuttle.
- MySQLicious sucks because it cannot use an index (`LIKE` with *leading* wild card; false hits on substrings)
- For MySQL, be sure to use ENGINE=InnoDB in order to get 'clustering' effects.

Related discussions (for MySQL):
[many:many mapping table optimization](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) ,
[ordered lists](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists) ,
and, especially for WP users,
[postmeta improvements](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta)